# Select Dropdown Automatically According to value from Database

Tags: php, html

I have very simple dropdown menu like below in my PHP page.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">FAQ Type :-</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select name="faq_type" id="faq_type" class="select2" required>
            <option value="0">Text</option>
            <option value="1">Image</option>
            <option value="2">Video</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want select Text, Image or Video selection automatically according to value I get from database, for other field I am able to echo like below

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <textarea name="question" id="question" rows="1" class="form-control" ><?php if(isset($_GET['faq_id'])){echo $row['question'];}?></textarea> 
</div>
```

How can I do same for dropdown ?

Edit : according to answer, I was able to do it but I have one small another issue in it, I want only set selected if `if(isset($_GET['faq_id']))` else want show normal all button as currently I am showing as above.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">FAQ Type :-</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['faq_id'])) {
            <select name="faq_type" id="faq_type" class="select2" required>
                <option value="0" <?php if($row['type'] == "0") echo "selected"; ?>>Text</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if($row['type'] == "1") echo "selected"; ?>>Image</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if($row['type'] == "2") echo "selected"; ?>>Video</option>
            </select>
        } else {

        }
        ?>      
    </div>
</div>
```

if I do like this, its giving me error like below

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\add_faq.php on line 169
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For drop down you can set selected field like this

```
        <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">FAQ Type :-</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <select name="faq_type" id="faq_type" class="select2" required>
                      <option value="0" <?php if($row['your_db_field'] == "0") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> >Text</option>
                      <option value="1" <?php if($row['your_db_field'] == "1") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> >Image</option>
                      <option value="2" <<?php if($row['your_db_field'] == "3") { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> >Video</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: sure. its asking me for wait some minutes. I will do it :)]

Comment: Hello! I have one another issue, can I edit my question? Thank

Comment: If the issue is different then you should post another question mate :)

Comment: @RajuBhatt I have edited my answer please try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro :)

Comment: Welcome mate we are all here to help and getting help. :)